# Qual o motivo na demora da primeira consulta ao Amazon RDS?

Tags: http, http-request, amazon-aws

Sempre após um logo período sem consultas, ao realizar uma requisição ao Amazon RDS (MySQL), há uma demora quase 20 segundos, enquanto as requisições seguintes acontecem normalmente, como pode-se ver na imagem, destacado no retângulo verde! Preciso resolver isto.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível causa para isso é você ter um pool de conexões expiradas (*timeout*) após o longo período.

Então, quando uma requisição chega, sua aplicação, framework ou servidor leva os 20 segundos para detectar o problema e conectar-se novamente ao banco de dados.

Possíveis soluções:

1. Configurar o seu gerenciador de conexões para fazer um "ping" no banco de dados e evitar que as conexões "morram". Essa ideia foi extraída [deste artigo](http://mysqlpreacher.com/wordpress/2010/06/mysql-jdbc-connector-autoreconnecttrue/).
2. Aumentar o *timeout* definido na variável [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).
3. Se sua aplicação é Java você pode usar o parâmetro `autoReconnect`, conforme mencionado na [documentação do driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

A primeira opção parece ser a mais recomendada.